# How to upload new file into GCP bucket?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gcp

I've found [excellent example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-storage-resource-sample/src/main/java/com/example/WebController.java) how to read/update existing file in GCP bucket:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Value("gs://${gcs-resource-test-bucket}/my-file.txt")
    private Resource gcsFile;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String readGcsFile() throws IOException {
        return StreamUtils.copyToString(
                this.gcsFile.getInputStream(),
                Charset.defaultCharset()) + "\n";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String writeGcs(@RequestBody String data) throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream os = ((WritableResource) this.gcsFile).getOutputStream()) {
            os.write(data.getBytes());
        }
        return "file was updated\n";
    }
}
```

But I can't find the way how to upload new file into GCP bucket using spring gloud GCP.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: You can check the official GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-java) on java code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Autowired
private Storage gcs;

public void upload(String report) {

    gcs.create(BlobInfo
                    .newBuilder("bucket_name", "fileName.json")
                    .build(),
            report.getBytes());

}
```